# Wordpress and twitter feed in slider

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

i am making fresh new wordpress theme. But i am stuck with twitter feed.

I tried several plugins and they are working fine, but i want to achive one effect.

**Put feeds in slider. So only 1 tweet will be at the time and then fading to 2nd etc**.

Is that possible ?

Any code/Suggestion/Reference will be very much helpful.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you need to at least make an attempt at it rather than hoping someone will build it for you. Instead of using a WP plugin, try building the TB carousel and adding the Twitter feeds in it using a jQuery plugin or even code you can grab from Twitter dev. Give it a shot and post your code and you will find a solution quickly.

Comment: I used this one , worked like charm :) http://sonnyt.com/tweetie-plugin/

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!